# Are semi-relevant comments okay?

Tags: discussion, comments

Comments on [my question about SawStop alternatives](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/847/are-there-any-alternatives-to-a-sawstop) seem less relevant to the question than they could be.

I don't mind a quick safety note, i.e. "How do I hold a router with my teeth?": "This is terribly unsafe and no one should ever do this". But at some point the discussion is unhelpful.

This could be related to any subject, but I think safety is often going to be a hot topic for comments.

Is there a policy in place for this? Is my reaction unwarranted?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the off-topic comments annoying when they turn into side discussions. If a comment discussion devolves into a heated debate I would suggest flagging those comments for removal. You can also post a comment asking people to bring the discussion back on-topic.

Of course, once the comments exceed a certain number, they get collapsed and only the highest-voted comments are shown by default. Then you have to click a link to show all comments.

While they're certainly annoying, off-topic comments are largely harmless in most cases. However, if we see that certain types of comments often spark debates which have a negative impact, we should consider discouraging those types of comments and recommending that people discuss them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22025/the-workshop) instead.

Comment: Sounds like my sentiments as well just better worded.

Comment: Exactly I quickly nixed the budding bragging contest on [my kickback question](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-prevent-dangerous-kickback-on-a-table-saw#comment144_21) with a suggestion to move it to chat, and to avoid my inbox getting too full.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your reaction is unwarranted however I would like to think that we are trying not to be *as* strict here (Like SO where saying thanks can get your hand slapped) to allow off the cuff comments like that. As long as they don't get out of hand.

They are in fact just comments. As long as they are not abusive or spam it should be OK to get a little cheeky. It lightens the atmosphere. Over time they will be removed anyway. People tend to glaze over comments and focus the answers anyway.

**On going conversations**, of this caliber, have no place in comments and should remain/be moved in the [The WorkShop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22025/the-workshop) chat room as to not clutter up a good Q&A. Then, if useful information comes to light from that conversation it can be added as an answer or an edit.